# Is the docker daemon running? Spring-boot java project on Ubuntu

Tags: spring-boot

I have Ubuntu 22.04,

I have Java Spring-boot project, I run Idea, then run docker-compose.yml and get this message:

Cannot connect to the docker daemon  at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
Is the docker daemon running? (Details:[13]  Permission denied)

What should I check?

Comment: Docker daemon is the actual docker server that will be respond back for your docker commands. How did installed docker.. ?

Comment: I installed Docker by terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take this perfect Tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04

The important section for you is: Step 2 — Executing the Docker Command Without Sudo (Optional)

Your Problem is that you try to use docker without sudo. You have no permission for that.

Comment: thanks, but not really this stuff.  I have problem when I run manually docker-compose.yml   file in the project folder

Comment: Is this correct?  I write:    su - ${anatoly}, put in password  and get: Authentication failure.